# A Basic Doubt In Vocabulary used in Probability Questions

Tags: probability

Ques : From A bag containing $8$ White Balls ( Numbered as $W_1,W_2...W_8$), and $5$ Black Balls(Numbered as $B_9,B_{10}..$, four balls are drawn at Random **One by one without replacement** Find The probability that exactly two of them is white ?

I know How to solve it However my Question is... Is there a difference between the statements :

$S_1$ : Drawing $4$ Balls at Random  One-by-One without replacement

$S_2$ : Drawing $4$ Balls At random

I Think there is as according To $S_1$  if say I draw at first chance $W_8$,then $W_7 ,B_9,W_1$ Then it should be different from Taking out $W_1$ at first Chance then $W_7,B_9,W_8$ As basically We can distinguish these configurations on the basis that In one $W_8$ comes In last whereas in other it comes in first(Right ??), whereas $S_2$ considers both configurations same as there is no choice of choosing something at first and at last (Right ??) .

But according to my interpretation answer should be
$$\left( \frac{8_{C_2}\cdot5_{C_2}\cdot4!/(2!\cdot2!)}{13\cdot12\cdot11\cdot10}\right)$$,but answer given is $$\left(\frac{8_{C_2} \cdot 5_{C_2}}{13_{C_4}}\right)$$

What Is wrong My interpretation or The answer given (which I think is based on $S_2$?

Comment: I think you want {}_nC_k for the choose function.

Comment: Your'e answer is the same as theirs except for your division by $(2!\cdot{}2!)$. I don't see why you added that.

Comment: Also the difference between $S_1$ and $S_2$ is that $S_2$ is vague and does't say whether balls are replaced or taken out one at a time, all together, ect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Mosquite that the main feature of $S_2$ is that it is vague, arguably too much so.

Without any further given context, I would generally interpret "drawn at random" to mean "without replacement", but there isn't really a logically valid reason to interpret it that way instead of "with replacement". Without replacement however seems to be more commonly used, both in practice problems written by instructors and also in real life, e.g. more people seem to keep the fish they catch than practice catch-and-release.

When one has infinite populations (which is not the case in your problem) then the difference doesn't matter since the number of balls drawn does not affect the probability of drawing any given type of ball.

In the finite case it does matter and therefore $S_2$ arguably does not give enough information about how to solve the problem.